# Avoid automatic switch from dynamic table refrence to worksheet and range

Tags: vba, excel, reference, range, cells

I am developing an automated Excel template to handle data and create dynamic plots based on the data. So I select my data from a dynamic table, a shown:

[image: First step]

Once I have referenced it, then Excel automatically changes my values to a range, selecting the worksheet that has this data, as shown:

[image: Excel's action to avoid]

How can I avoid this automatic change that is made by Excel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter that excel changes the Table reference to a range. When data is added to or taken away from the table, then the range will be updated in the chart.

Comment: Yes, that is actually what happens... But in this case, the reference is made before the dynamic table exists. I am working with VBA for Excel so that the worksheet that holds the dynamic table is also created after the reference is made. For this case the name DataTable is specified by the following code: `ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, rng, , xlYes).Name = "DataTable"`

Comment: Have you considered updating the chart range with VBA after the worksheet is created?

Comment: No, I have not considered that idea. It turns out to be a really good idea, I did not think. Thanks.